# Shell scripting -How to retrieve the list of strings within pipe delimiter

Tags: bash, shell

I am a beginner in shell scripting. I have to write a code to get the list of databases which are modified after our last export from one server and import those to our new server.
I could successfully execute the query to get the list of databases which are modified from old server using a java CLI. But it gives the output as below

```
|DATABASE_NAME|
|CONSUMER_B1|
|MOSAIC|
|ADMIN|
|AML|
etc
```

So I want to retrieve the database list within this pipe using a shell command and put it in a for loop or some loop and using an export command (which is already tested) need to get export of each of this databases one by one.

For example, prototype would be like below. databasename should be replaced with each of the databases which is in the above list.

```
Loop
./export.sh --login abc --password *** --file export_delta.vql --server "localhost:9999/databasename" 2>&1 >> $logfile
end loop
```

Could anyone please help in how to implement it in shell script?

Thanks!

Comment: Piping to `tr -d '|'` will remove all the `|` characters. Is that all you need to do?

Comment: You can also `cut -d\| -f2`, i.e. extract the second column taking `|` as the delimiter.

Comment: You could. use `sed 's/|//'` to process the names too.

Comment: The simplest approach is to use pure Bash: You can start from a simple example, e.g. `database='|AML|'; echo "${database:1:-1}"` — that’s the basic idea. Now nest that into a loop over the lines, e.g. `while IFS= read -r database; do ...; done`. Finally, your output redirection needs to be either `>> "$logfile" 2>&1` or, the same thing in a shorter form, `&>> "$logfile"`. What you have there now appends (only) `stdout` to the `"$logfile"` and then redirects `stderr` into (the default) `stdout`.